# how can I use the react-native-datetime-modal-picker with input?

Tags: react-native, expo

Everyone.
I want to link the input box and date-picker.
so I have tried this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Item, Input, Label } from 'native-base';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import moment from 'moment';
...
  render() {
    const { label, value, mode, displayFormat, ...other } = this.props;
    const { show } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Item {...other} floatingLabel onPress={this.showDateTimePicker}>
          <Label>{label}</Label>
          <Input editable={false} value={value ? moment(value).format(displayFormat) : ''} onPress={this.showDateTimePicker} />
        </Item>
        <DateTimePicker
          date={value ? new Date(value) : new Date()}
          isVisible={show}
          mode={mode}
          onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
          onCancel={this.hideDateTimePicker}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
...
```

but unfortunately, onPress event doesn't handle when the TextInput disabled in IOS.
so, please help me to solve this problem.

Here is the project environment.

```
...
"expo": "^34.0.1",
...
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"native-base": "^2.13.7",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
...
```

[Watch on Expo Snake (before)](https://snack.expo.io/@whitedragon226/formdatetimepicker)
[Watch on Expo Snake (fixed)](https://snack.expo.io/@whitedragon226/formdatetimepicker1)

Comment: Try to wrap item with TouchableOpacity and use onpress  on it

Comment: @oleg. I have tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: I used native-base to build this app.

Comment: Can you   post expo snack example?

Comment: @oleg, i have created the expo snake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example, test only on IOS
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/formdatetimepicker

Comment: Hi, Oleg. you mean there is no way to get focus event from disabled TextInput. right?

Comment: This is correct answer how to link DateTimePicker with TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer for time (24h), can be adapted easy for date as well

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View,TextInput } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import moment from 'moment';

export const Schedule = () => {
    const [HHTime, setHHTime] = useState({ from: "", to: "", showPickerFrom: false, showPickerTo: false });
    return (
        <View>
            <Text> Horaire des happyhours:</Text>
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    value={HHTime?.from ? moment(HHTime?.from).format("HH:mm") : ''}
                    onFocus={() => setHHTime({ ...HHTime, showPickerFrom: true })}
                    style={style.input}
                />
                <DateTimePickerModal
                    mode="time"
                    date={HHTime?.from ? new Date(HHTime?.from) : new Date()}
                    isVisible={HHTime?.showPickerFrom}
                    onConfirm={(val) => setHHTime({ ...HHTime, showPickerFrom: false, from: val })}
                    onCancel={() => setHHTime({ ...HHTime, showPickerFrom: false, from: '' })}
                    is24Hour={true}
                />
                <Text> - </Text>
                <TextInput
                    value={HHTime?.to ? moment(HHTime?.to).format("HH:mm") : ''}
                    onFocus={() => setHHTime({ ...HHTime, showPickerTo: true })}
                    style={style.input}
                />
                <DateTimePickerModal
                    mode="time"
                    date={HHTime?.to ? new Date(HHTime?.to) : new Date()}
                    isVisible={HHTime?.showPickerTo}
                    onConfirm={(val) => setHHTime({ ...HHTime, showPickerTo: false, to: val })}
                    onCancel={() => setHHTime({ ...HHTime, showPickerTo: false, to: '' })}
                    is24Hour={true}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```